# Synchronize real time updates while getting data from API

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The App I'm working on fire data updates every second and what I did until now is working very well but now I'm encountering a problem.

Basically I'm starting to listen the SSE (server sent events) as soon as I finished to get the whole data from the API and it result in a miss synchronization between the data I just got and the updates received while the get was running.

The ajax call duration at the beginning is about 20, 30 seconds and in that time I'm missing the updates for a few items.

If I start to listen the SSE as soon as the app load the issue is that if I receive an update and I still don't have that object in the collection the update is missing anyway...

I'm using Angular for the entire application and the code looks quite similar to this at the beginning:

```
var source = new EventSource('/updates');
$scope.items_01 = [];
$scope.items_02 = [];

$q.all([
    getList(first, [], 0),
    getList(second, [], 0)
])
.then(function (data) {
    $scope.items_01 = data[0];
    $scope.items_02 = data[1];
    startStreaming();
});

function startStreaming() {
    source.addEventListener('items_01', handleItems01Callback, false);
    source.addEventListener('items_02', handleItems02Callback, false);
}
```

How can I keep synchronized the data I get with the updates I receive while getting, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start listening to the SSEs right away and buffer the incoming updates. Once you get the full snapshot, start applying the updates.

The potential problem that comes to mind is that some of the updates might already be applied to the snapshot. You would need to have some additional information that would allow you to know that, so that you can skip those updates.

Comment: I did it like you suggested and it seems to work fine. Thanks